# What is the difference between mapping objects in an Object type and a Dictionary type

Tags: actionscript-3

```
public var obj:Object;
public var dictionary:Dictionary;


public function MyClass(){

    obj = new Object();
    dictionary = new Dictionary();

    obj["1"] = 1;
    obj["2"] = 2;

    dictionary["3"] = 3;
    dictionary["4"] = 4;
}

public function returnFromObject(parameter:String):int{

     return obj[parameter];
}

public function returnFromDictionary(parameter:String):int{

     return dictionary[parameter];
}
```

They can serve the same purpose to me. Unless there's an obvious performance hit in using either of them that I'not aware of.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems like Dictionary is much faster than object and array according to this:

http://www.zombieflambe.com/actionscript-3/as3-dictionary-class-array-object-benchmark/

Comment: Haha 10 seconds into reading that and laughing already, point for article with good nerd humor.

Comment: Also good info thanks for the link, so it seems Dictionary acts similar to a HashMap in Java or whatever where it can almost directly access any point in the collection directly without much overhead.

Answer (score 2):

The difference is in being able to use an object as a key rather than a string in the case of a Dictionary.  Outside of that I'm not aware of any major differences (don't recall ever seeing any real benchmarks on these though, so if anyone is the wiser please let us know).

http://gskinner.com/blog/archives/2006/07/as3_dictionary_.html

Only reference to performance on the page is a brief one in the comments, generally as they state I find these to be wishy washy and dependent on the application.

Answer (score 1):

While there are probably more differences than this, my first thought was variable declaration, and the ability to loop through Objects.

```
var obj:Object = new Object();
obj.a = "test1";
obj.b = "test2";
obj.c = "test3";

for each (var prop in obj) trace(prop); //traces "test1, test2, test3"
```

More information here: http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Dictionary.html

Comment: With both Object and Dictionary you can loop thru keys with `for..in` and values with `for each..in`